# Get data from table, Using Rows as Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have following data in my table.

[alt text http://img26.imageshack.us/img26/3746/productfield.png](http://img26.imageshack.us/img26/3746/productfield.png)

I want to extract ProductId which has this criteria,

```
FieldValue = 1.0 and FieldValue = 'Y' and FieldValue = 'N'
```

This is not possible using following query

```
select * from MyTable
WHERE (FieldId = 50 AND (FieldValue BETWEEN '1.0' AND '1.0')) 
AND (FieldId = 55 AND FieldValue = 'Y') 
AND (FieldId = 60 AND FieldValue = 'N')
```

and I can't use query like this. This also fetch ProductId 103 and 104.

```
select * from MyTable
WHERE (FieldId = 50 AND (FieldValue BETWEEN '1.0' AND '1.0')) 
OR (FieldId = 55 AND FieldValue = 'Y') 
OR (FieldId = 60 AND FieldValue = 'N')
```

[alt text http://img690.imageshack.us/img690/16/productfieldresult.png](http://img690.imageshack.us/img690/16/productfieldresult.png)

**I don't know ProductId in advance. In-fact I want to extract ProductId using FieldValue criteria. I CAN'T USE ProductId in my where clause because I don't know. Only I know Is the fieldValue and FieldId.**

Thanks for help!

Comment: I only need ProductId matching criteria I have mentioned. There is no need to re arange columns in a row.

Comment: I feel that dotjoe solution is much more relevant because u want to perform the search based on the fieldvalue criteria and not on both fieldvalue & fieldid. (:

Comment: Indeed, that's a good question: Do you want to filter only on FieldValue or on (FieldId, FieldValue)-combinations? Your question sounds more like the former, but your SQL examples and "common sense" lead towards the second...

Comment: Heinzi got correct sense from my SQL Examples. I want that particular ProductId which fulfill my criteria. @dotjoe is also correct but I accepted @Heinzi because he comes with my solution a little earlier.

I am thankful to all people who answered my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want the following:

```
SELECT ProductId from myTable
 WHERE ProductId IN (SELECT ProductId FROM myTable WHERE FieldId = 50 AND FieldValue = '1.0')
   AND ProductId IN (SELECT ProductId FROM myTable WHERE FieldId = 55 AND FieldValue = 'Y') 
   AND ProductId IN (SELECT ProductId FROM myTable WHERE FieldId = 60 AND FieldValue = 'N')
```

(You can put one of the criteria in the outer SELECT, but I guess it's easier to read this way.)

Answer (score 1):

```
select distinct t1.productid
from mytable t1
inner join mytable t2 on t1.productid = t2.productid
inner join mytable t3 on t2.productid = t3.productid
where t1.fieldvalue = '1.0' and t1.fieldid = 50
and t2.fieldvalue = 'Y' and t2.fieldid = 55
and t3.fieldvalue = 'N' and t3.fieldid = 60
```

Comment: good answer...exactly what the OP's criteria is... only on fieldvalue  and not on FieldId..

Comment: but you forgot to add mytable in the inner joins.

inner join mytable t2 on t1.productid = t2.productid
inner join mytablet t3 on t2.productid = t3.productid

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

ProductId = 101 and FieldValue IN ('1.0', 'Y', 'N')

[Edit]

Maybe you can use a subquery like this?

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE ProductId = 
-- SubQuery for searching ProductId based on FieldId and FieldValue
(SELECT TOP 1 ProductId
FROM MyTable
WHERE (FieldId = 50 AND (FieldValue BETWEEN '1.0' AND '1.0'))
```

Comment: ProductId is the value which I want to get using FieldValue criteria.

So I can't use PrdouctId = 101

Comment: Not so obviously. Your question is not so obvious, indeed. A field in a row will never have two values at once, as Guffa stated. My "IN" solution is equivalent to him's

Comment: @Muhammad  check it again... this time using a subquery

Answer (score 0):

The FieldValue for a record can never have two values at once, that's why a condition like `x=1 and x=2` never can be true.

You want to use `or` between the conditions:

```
ProductId = 101 and (FieldValue = '1.0' or FieldValue = 'Y' and FieldValue = 'N')
```

Edit:
If you have to find a ProductId with that combination of FieldId and FieldValue values, you have to do some joining:

```
select * from MyTable
where ProductId = (
  select ProductId
  from MyTable m
  inner join MyTable m2 on m2.ProductId = m.ProductId and m2.FieldId = 55 and FieldValue = 'Y'
  inner join MyTable m3 on m3.ProductId = m.ProductId and m3.FieldId = 60 and FieldValue = 'N'
  where FieldId = 50 and FieldValue = '1.0'
)
```

Comment: Thanks, I don't know ProductId in advance so I can't use it in my Where. Any solution using temp table etc.

Comment: I see. I added a solution above.